# Langenscheidt basic german vocabulary translation issue or typo?

Tags: german-to-english

I have the Langenscheidt Basic German Vocabulary book (1991 Langenscheidt KG edition) which I LOVE, but I noticed a very interesting "typo" or perhaps a "mis-translation" on page Roman Numeral VIII, in the last sentence of the paragraph headed "Why These Words?". The sentence:

> The critical choice of example sentences was made by native speakers on an outside of our regular staff.

Of course, the phrase "on an outside of our regular staff" does not make sense in English. Does anyone have an opinion as to whether this was simply a typographic error or whether this is a typical or atypical example of a German author writing in English?

Comment: Thanks for trusting our English skills that much, but I think this could be better answered  in one of the English language SEs by someone who *isn't* a native German speaker writing in English. To me it just looks like "an" should be "and", and then the sentence sounds more or less fine to me (as a German native speaker).

Comment: The question does seem off topic, but just to save everyone time... It is an error and I'd rephrase it "not on our regular staff" or "outside of our regular staff". Native German speakers do occasionally import word orders which don't work in English. A famous fictional example is from the Sherlock Holmes story "A Scandal in Bohemia": 'This account of you we have from all quarters received.' But I doubt it really helps to try to analyze a specific error and reverse engineer the thought processes involved. Sometimes an error is just an error.

Comment: @rdbury This indeed looks to me like "an" was originally meant to be "and" (so just a letter went missing) and the "on" seems to be a remnant of a previous revision of the text. Stuff like that often hapens when texts are revised by different persons in a hurry. I wouldn't try and explain anything "specifically German" into this error.

Comment: Just to complete, if @HalvarF is right, the meaning would be "native speakers, both from our regular staff and from outside." A possible German source would then be "Muttersprachler sowohl innerhalb als auch außerhalb der Reihen unserer Mitarbeiter".

Comment: @tofro - I was thinking that they meant to say that none the native speakers were regular staff. It's hard to say for sure; one problem with getting the grammar is that the intended meaning becomes uncertain. But upon reexamination it seems more likely they meant "both ... and". Occam's razor would imply it's a simple typo, nothing to do with the differences between German and English.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence looks like a copy-paste error, that is, somebody editing and shortening the text *accidentally a few words*, as it were. If we emend "made by native speakers […] outside of our staff" it makes sense.

There is no telling, if "on a ..." was part of a different formulation, what it would have been. Something like "on a [voluntary basis]" is very likely (i.e. Praktikanten or freie Mitarbeiter).

> Of course, the phrase "on an outside of our regular staff" does not make sense in English

"the outside" is always definite and "outside" an adverb but we can also find "an outside man" with "an" indefinite article. It's entirely possible, obviously, that this has passed proof reading when they already knew what's being said and so didn't read closely.